# How to connect à mass transit consumer to an exchange created by a different application

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm using Masstransit with RabbitMq to communicate between two web applications .net core.
In the publisher application I publish a message to an exchange 'producer'.

```
rabbitConfigurator.Message<TMessage>(x => x.SetEntityName("producer"));
```

In the same application I have a consumer-A of said messages and that works fine (the consumer has an exchange and a queue as recommended by rabbit/masstransit connected to the producer exchange)

```
rabbitConfigurator.ReceiveEndpoint("consumer-A", x =>
            {
                x.Consumer<TConsumer>(context);
                x.Bind("producer");
            });
```

In a second application I'm trying to setup another consumer-B of the same message type connected to the exchange 'producer'.

```
rabbitConfigurator.ReceiveEndpoint("consumer-B", x =>
                {
                    x.Consumer<TConsumer>(context);
                    x.Bind("producer");
                });
```

However messages destined for this second application are getting sent to a skipped queue.  From what I can see this second consumer is correctly configured in RabbitMq though.

I can't see what I'm missing.

Edit: In the producing application I can also successfully receive messages in a second consumer.  But from another web application it doesn't work - perhaps something to do with the fact that there's a differetn connection/channel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages sent to the `producer` exchange should be in a format that can be deserialized by MassTransit. If they aren't, you'll need to add a message deserializer which can support the message type. If it is `application/json` then you'll need to add the `RawJsonMessageDeserializer` to the receive endpoint.

If the messages are in the correct format, verify that you have a consumer on the receive endpoint that can consume that message type. Message types must match entirely, including namespace, to be consumed. More details are available [in the documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/messages.html).

Comment: Yes, the namespace did not match.

Comment: As a followup question, if my second application was written in another language or without using MassTransit how would I receive the message - how does the namespace and name of the message manifest itself in pure RabbitMq terms (it does not appear to be a routing key)?

Comment: The [interoperability guide](https://masstransit-project.com/architecture/interoperability.html) has the details, or if you use RawJson it will deserialize into any type you request (T) but you'd want to have a separate receive endpoint or each type in that case, or do you own magic on it.